# Inverse Transform Sampling for General Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

On the Wikipedia page for [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), only continuous random variables are considered, and I don't quite understand why. Given $X\in\mathbb R$ with cdf $F$, let $X(u)=\min\{x\in\mathbb R:F(x)\ge u\}$ for $u\in(0,1)$. With $U$ being uniform on $[0,1]$, we have $\mathbb P(X(U)\le x)=\mathbb P(U\le F(x))=F(x)$ since $X(u)\le x$ if and only if $u\le F(x)$.
This means that $X$ and $X(U)$ have the same cdf, and thereby the same distribution (using a generator for the Borel algebra).

**Question**: Why does the Wikipedia page restrict to this special case? Is my reasoning above wrong, does the general version come with a different name, or does the discussion on Wikipedia focus on the continuous case for simplicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia case likely deals with continuous random variables for simplicity.

If $F^{-1}_X$ is the generalized inverse function (as defined in the question body) of $F_X(x):=P(X\leq x)$ for a real-valued rv $X$, then $P(F^{-1}_X(U)\leq x)=F_X(x)$ for $U\sim \textrm{Uniform}(0,1)$. However, the statement that $F_X(X)\sim U$ is valid with continuous $X$. For a reference on both of these facts see [McNeil et al. Proposition 5.2., p. 186](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691166277).

To complete the argument, since the law of $F_{X}^{-1}(U)$ agrees with the law of $X$ on a $\cap$-stable family of sets which generate $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then $F_X^{-1}(U)\sim X$. This is valid for all real-valued rvs $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A minor correction: [This](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Quantitative_Risk_Management/mpTknQEACAAJ?hl=en) is the reference, the revised version differs there.